# Does Malloc get memory from RAM or cache

Tags: android, android-ndk, malloc

I have a Native android app which Makes a lot of calls to Malloc. I am trying to allocate a chunk of the RAM and then run some memory intensive tasks to see how my Android device handles it. But I am not sure if the device is taking memory from the RAM or other sources of memory. Is there a way to find out? If it is taking memory from the cache, how do I make it so I am allocating the memory only from the RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am not sure if the device is taking memory from the RAM or other sources of memory

[`malloc()` allocates memory from the process' heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), which in turn comes from the device RAM. It has done so for decades.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer! Is there some forum or website where I could read more about this? If malloc only accesses the RAM then when is the cache used? Does the OS automatically move stuff from RAM to cache in the case the data is used often and would that be the only way data gets stored to the cache?

Comment: @AndroidDev93: "Is there some forum or website where I could read more about this?" -- `malloc()` has been around for about three decades. You might start by clicking on the Wikipedia link in my answer. "If malloc only accesses the RAM then when is the cache used?" -- I have no idea what you think "the cache" is.

Comment: Forgive me if my questions don't make sense, but I am kind of a noob when it comes to the low level aspects. I understand that the cache is memory which is used to store commonly used data so that the CPU can retrieve the data faster. From what I have understood so far, I assume the OS basically handles writing to the cache by itself. So it would choose which data needs to be stored in the cache and write to it. But I was curious if there was actually anyway to directly write to the cache on Android?

Comment: @AndroidDev93: "I assume the OS basically handles writing to the cache by itself" -- not really. Determining the contents of on-board CPU caches are usually handled by the C compiler, in this case the one that compiled the OS. "But I was curious if there was actually anyway to directly write to the cache on Android?" -- not really.